# Video ads using Google admob in android

Tags: android, admob

How to get video ads using admob in Android? When I tried everything seems to be working fine however I am getting a full screen image not a video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have control over what type of content is sent for an interstitial. It is up to the ad network. I suspect you are unlikely to receive video ads unless you have a very high number of requests.

Comment: FYI: using mopub, I am able to get video ads. With admob, so far no video ads.